# How to execute repeated dos commands using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> I am using below codes with c# for executing doss command in the comment line i executed notepad and in the comment line i tried to execute excel but nobody running if i comment any one from notepad or excel then it executes. I want to execute dos commands one by one weather previous command finish its process or not.

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C notepad";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C excel";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the Arguments property twice you are replacing "/C notepad" with "/C excel". The process is launching cmd.exe and passing only "/C excel" to it as an argument.

I suspect that cmd.exe cannot find the Excel exe when it's passed as a "/C" argument. This would explain why you don't see anything executing. You may need to specify the complete path to Excel.

If you want to execute both Notepad and Excel, you will need to launch them one after another by first setting one argument then calling `Start` for each application.

Something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C notepad";
process.Start();
startInfo.Arguments = "/C {Insert the full path to Excel exe}excel";
process.Start();
```

Alternatively, you can launch both applications launched from the process rather then as parameters to cmd.exe. `Process` itself is cmd.exe. This will allow the OS to have a better chance of finding the application using the Windows Path variables

Something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;

startInfo.FileName = "notepad";
process.Start();

startInfo.FileName = "excel";
process.Start();
```

Comment: Now Executing both process thanx Linos Pechos ...it helped me ..ok but when i am trying to placing                                            
  startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; It execute only one.

Comment: can you tell me how to take dos output in string? like string str = " Dos commans" etc.